# Mutually dependant using definitions

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, using, c++17

I have some mutually dependent template instances. Normally I'd just forward declare them but I don't see how this is possible. Here is an example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

using Tuple = std::tuple<int,TupleContainer>;
using TupleContainer = std::unique_ptr<Tuple>;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Can't write `Tuple` first due to needing `TupleContainer`, can't write `TupleContainer` first due to needing `Tuple`.

How can I forward declare one of the using definitions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a recursive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563661/how-to-define-a-recursive-type)

Comment: boost can possibly do what you want. Here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898763/817643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it by using a thin wrapper class around std::tuple and using a forward declaration.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

struct Tuple;
using TupleContainer = std::unique_ptr<Tuple>;

struct Tuple : public std::tuple<int,TupleContainer>{
    using std::tuple<int,TupleContainer>::tuple;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You need a real pointer somewhere, just like if you were to try and have a recursive structure definition it fails because it wouldn't be able to stop.

```
using my_tuple = std::tuple<int, std::tuple<int>*>;
```