# Recursive alias template

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, c++17, adjacency-list

I'm creating an adjacency list to modelize an **oriented weighted graph**, and i'd like to know if **recursive alias templates** are possibe.
I've tried something like this

```
template<class edge_data>
using graph_test = std::set<std::map<std::set<graph_test>::const_pointer, edge_data>>;
```

(each entry of the set is a map, and each map represents a vertex. each entry of the maps are edges: keys are pointers to other vertices, values are weight. the pointers are not invalidated on insertion)

This produces an error : `'graph_test': undeclared identifier`.

I know I could use `std::any` to avoid this problem, but it look a bit 'dangerous', even if I know what I'm doing.

Do you have any suggestions/ideas that might solve this problem ?

EDIT 1:
As [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) pointed it out, the way I create my *const_pointer* could not be correct. I came up with this code (modifications in italic):

```
template<class edge_data>
    using graph_test = std::set<std::map<graph_test<edge_data>::const_pointer, edge_data>>;
```

The problem and the error are still here, but it's a least one mistake fixed.

EDIT 2:
I took a look at [bipll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749717/bipll)'s solution, which was very relevant, and [Dani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362589/dani)'s comment, showing a probable lack of `typedef` keyword.
I came up with this piece of code, and it compiles:

```
template<class edge_data> struct graph_test
    : std::set<typename std::map<typename graph_test<edge_data>::const_pointer, edge_data>> {
    using std::map<typename graph_test<edge_data>::const_pointer, edge_data>::map;
};
```

I will mark with question as solved, thank you very much for your time and help :)

Comment: `std::set<T>` expects `T` to be a type, but `graph_test` is not a type - it's a class template, an infinite family of types. For that reason alone, `std::set<graph_test>` already doesn't make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a recursive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563661/how-to-define-a-recursive-type)

Comment: Well it's the same kind of problem, but I'm using an alias template instead of a typedef, so it wouldn't have helped a lot. But you're a bit of right, it kind of looks similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your definition, `graph_test` lacks a template parameter, and a `typename` is missing. Besides, a type cannot be an alias to itself, its expansion would create an infinite dependency graph. You can make it a real type, not an alias:

```
template<class edge_data> struct graph_test
    :std::set<
        typename std::map<typename std::set<graph_test<edge_data>>::const_pointer, edge_data>>
{
    using std::map<typename std::set<graph_test<edge_data>>::const_pointer, edge_data>>::map;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer looks great :) However I got many errors when I tried it, do you think it could come from the compilers arguments ?

Comment: I think you're missing typename before `std::set<graph_test<edge_data>>::const_pointer`